# CSS scroll down animation process trail line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to css animation. I want to make animated scroll down steps process trail line.

for example some what like this "how it works section".

where should I start ?? what should i search on google.

https://www.societyone.com.au/

Comment: You can use this: http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/docs/animation.GSAP.html#Scene.tweenChanges which responds to scroll bar movements.

Comment: for beginners level ??

Answer (score 1):

Try using wow.js

It is extremely user-friendly and easy to implement on your site.

Check it out [here](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html)

As per their instructions, you just have to -

1. Link to the CSS animation library
2. Link and activate WOW.js in the `<head>` section
3. Make an element revealable using the classes available in the library
4. Choose the animation style (from the animate.css library)

Don't forget to call or download the animate.css code from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css) for the effects.

For a demo of what you can do, check out [this page](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/) and scroll down for different effects available to choose from.

All the best!